# QListWidget выбор элемента

Tags: c++, qt

Как проверить, был ли выбран элемент в `QListWidget`?

Answer (score 2):

Подключитесь к сигналу `QListWidget::currentRowChanged` и проверяйте его аргумент `currentRow` на неотрицательность:

```
void MyClass::onCurrentRowChangeSlot(int currentRow)
{
    if(currentRow >= 0)
        // Выделена строка по номером currentRow
    else
        // Выделение исчезло
}
```

Если же отслеживание выделения требуется для задания доступности какого-нибудь элемента управления, например кнопки, можно упростить содержимое слота до единственной строки:

```
void MyClass::onCurrentRowChangeSlot(int currentRow)
{
    myButton.setEnabled(currentRow >= 0);
}
```

Либо то же самое с помощью лямбда-слота:

```
connect(list, &QListWidget::currentRowChanged, [&myButton](int currentRow)
{
    myButton.setEnabled(currentRow >= 0);
});
```

Comment: скорее currentRow > -1, 0 вроде как тоже валидный индекс

Comment: @Александр, или `currentRow  >= 0`. Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Что есть `myButton`?

Comment: @alexolut, некая кнопка.

Comment: @Arhad я про тип. В двух примерах кода он разный.

Comment: тяжело с этими виджетами, только кажется на первый взгляд что проще чем model/view

Comment: @alexolut, а, вот вы про что. Ну так [это не моя правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/665608/3).

Comment: @Arhad пока ответ не "общий" за его качество отвечает первый автор, имхо.

Comment: @alexolut, понял, исправил, спасибо.